# DC voltage regulation

Tags: voltage

I have torodial transformer output of 25 0 25 V AC.
After rectification i get +-37 V AC dual rail.
That is total of 74V DC 37+37
How can I step down this voltage to +-45[image: DC aotput is 25 0 25 V after rectification it is +/-37 and I need +/-45]

Comment: Zener-NPN regulator. Google it.

Comment: You have +/-37 V and you want +/-45 V? You need to step _up_, yes? How much current and what max ripple do you need?

Comment: No i need to step dow from total of +-74 V to +-45

Comment: That's a high voltage?

Comment: "*No i need to step dow from total of +-74 V to +-45*" you are confusing yourself and us. You have a max DC of 37V and you need 45V. You have a min DC of -37V and you need -45V. Both of those are step-up. Now if you just need a single +45V supply.... that is different.

Comment: So the voltage +-37 is like 37 ? Than yes I need to step up to +-45V

Comment: You mean you have 74V peak-to-peak and you want 45V peak-to-peak, or to say a different way: +/- 22.5V

Comment: I thought that 74v eguals to 37+37

Comment: Please show a scematic diagram of your power supply (hit CTRL-M while editing your question to open the schematic editor), and show the voltages you actually require, as well as those produced by the power supply.

Comment: AC output from transformer is 25 0 25 V and I need +/-45V DC on output

Comment: You seem to be getting a bit confused here. What you want is three voltages, a positive DC voltage, zero volts, and a negative DC voltage.

+/-45 means you want +45V, 0V , -45V. Is this correct?

Comment: yes i want +45 0 -45

Comment: So you have +25, 0, -25, and you want +45, 0, -45? In that case, you definitely need to step up.

Comment: and how do I step up ?

Comment: @patrik The ideal solution to achieve what you want is to use a smaller transformer (+15 0 -15).

Comment: How accurate does the 45 V *really* need to be? 30-0-30 V transformers are readily available and would give you about 42 V for each of the negative and positive rails. What is it going to be used in?

Comment: For an amplifier with TDA7294 or 7293

Comment: What kind of current draw do you expect on your rails?

Comment: Around 3,5 Amps

Comment: Both the TDA7294 and 7293 will run on +/-37V, if you're powering them with the rails.  The 7293 runs on +/- 10-40V and the 7294 +/- 12-50V.

Comment: A TDA7294 will work fine with +/-37 V rails. What is the current rating of the transformer that you have?

Comment: It is 200VA 4Amps

Comment: Those fuses look a bit under-rated for the current. Also, you should not need voltage regulators (just capacitors to smooth the supply, as you have shown) for the power rails of the amplifier. And an LM317 is inadequate for this particular task anyway w.r.t. current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TDA7294 ([datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/ab/d6/fa/99/84/36/49/ee/CD00000017.pdf/files/CD00000017.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000017.pdf)) will work fine with a power supply of +/-34 V.

A feature in its description is

> Thanks to the wide voltage range and to the high out current capability it is able to supply the highest power into both 4Ω and 8Ω loads
>   even in presence of poor supply regulation, with high Supply Voltage Rejection.

This is encouraging, because it reads as if an ordinary audio amp power supply will be fine for it, i.e. no voltage regulators are needed.

Looking around the internet, it appears that you can [add some film-type capacitors](http://www.tnt-audio.com/clinica/ssps1_e.html) to the secondary side of the transformer to get a slightly cleaner supply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVYfFg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(If you put any filter capacitors on the mains side of the transformer then they must have the appropriate X rating.)

For a transformer, you will need a "timed" fuse rather than one which blows quickly because there can be a short but large inrush current when power is applied to it. For a *toroidal* transformer, you may want to be a little bit more generous with the current rating as the inrush current can be higher than for a laminated core one.

You could use two 6800 μF capacitors in parallel in place of each 10000 μF capacitor if makes it easier to fit into the available space, especially if it means you can use ones with a 63 V rating instead of 50 V.

**Summary** You do not need to change the voltage from your rectified-and-smoothed supply.